# as.numeric function does not change vector type

Tags: r

I have a column in my dataset with numbers and NAs. When I try to import it, RStudio categorizes it as "character" instead of "numeric".

I tried using "as.numeric" function to convert that. I get the warning: "NAs introduced by coercion" and then nothing happens.

```
  str(my_data)
   Classes ‘tbl_df’, ‘tbl’ and 'data.frame':    131 obs. of  6 variables:
   $ labs_TotalChol       : num  NA 149 149 188 171 147 207 NA 131 136 ...
 $ labs_Creatinine      : num  NA NA NA NA 0.8 1 NA NA 0.7 0.7 ...
 $ PET_globalCFR        : chr  NA "2.87" "2.65" "2.65" ...
 $ RHI                  : num  NA 1.49 1.91 1.5 3.03 1.72 1.93 2.67 1.28 2.06 ...
 $ PET_avghr_stress     : num  NA 90 99.7 76 73 ...
 $ PET_RPPCorrected_rest: num  NA 2.09 2.1 2.24 2.11 2 2.75 1.07 2.72 2.24 ...
```

I use the code:

```
as.numeric(my_data$PET_globalCFR)
```

and get:

```
  [1]   NA 2.87 2.65 2.65 2.46 2.80 2.93 2.02 3.77 2.62 2.06   NA 2.73 2.40 2.95 2.97 2.69 2.61 2.17 2.80 2.59   NA 1.87 2.23   NA
 [26] 1.34 2.06 2.24 1.94 1.73 1.63   NA 1.72   NA 1.94 1.25 3.38   NA 2.09 2.68 2.91 1.94 2.41 2.50   NA   NA 2.79 2.14 3.77 2.10
 [51] 2.88 2.07 2.78   NA   NA   NA 1.54 2.38 2.29 1.40 2.21 2.36   NA 2.30 2.54 2.29 2.28 2.57 3.53   NA 2.34 3.84 1.50 2.19 2.16
 [76] 1.20 2.73 1.35 3.48 2.51 1.42 1.74 1.68   NA   NA 1.98   NA   NA 2.44 1.62 2.99 1.34 1.39 2.16 4.58 1.74   NA 2.21   NA 1.41
[101] 0.95 2.60 2.30 1.67 1.81 1.79   NA 1.60 3.24 3.20   NA 1.46   NA   NA   NA 2.65   NA   NA 2.80 1.67 3.49   NA   NA   NA   NA
[126]   NA   NA   NA 1.54   NA   NA
Warning message:
NAs introduced by coercion
```

Comment: Hi Armin, can you please edit your question and provide example data and code so we can see what you're doing? otherwise it's very difficult to help.

Comment: To help you with a problem like this, we need a [mcve] of the problem: that includes data, code, output/error generated by that code and your desired result.

Comment: Did you try `as.numeric(as.character(df[, 1]))`?

Comment: sounds like it's a factor. you can tell the class by `class(vector)` or `str(vector)`

Comment: Please show the code you are using. Are you assigning the result with `=` or `<-`?

Comment: @Gregor I'm not assigning anything. Just: `as.numeric(df$example)`. I want the "example" column in the dataset to be set as numeric.

Comment: @SymbolixAU I tried editing the question to answer some of the questions. Hope it makes sense.

Comment: "I would add the dataset here, but can't since it's confidential." - you can make up a dummy dataset, of just a couple of rows, rather than supplying your actual data

Comment: @SymbolixAU I edited the Q. Is this OK?

Comment: your `as.numeric()` call is doing exactly what you want. It's converting it to numeric. But don't forget you need to update the column in the data.frame `my_data$PET_globalCFR <- as.numeric(my_data$PET_globalCFR)`

Comment: @SymbolixAU That worked thanks! So basically I was converting it but I wasn't telling it to put that back in the df.

Comment: Exactly. If you have `x <- 1`, if you type `x + 2` you will see the result `3` printed, but `x` is unchanged. If you want to modify `x`, you have to do `x <- x + 2`, and now `x` is 3. It's exactly the same for the columns of your data frame.` `as.numeric(data$column)` prints the result. You may want to assign the result to a new column, to modify the original column, or something else. In this case, you want to modify the column, so you do `my_data$PET_globalCFR <- ...`

Comment: @Gregor Thanks so much!

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can import it as a character first, then filter to remove NA's (!is.NA) then convert to numeric.

Comment: This won't make a difference. `NA`s can be numeric or character, and converting between them isn't a problem. For example, `as.numeric(c("1", NA))`